# Как удалить все роли на сервере с помощью discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хочу сделать команду в своём боте, которая будет очищать роли. Я пробовал сделать так:

```
if(cmd === "clearroles") {
    message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => role.delete());
}
```

Но возникает ошибка:

```
(node:3748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Role
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает т.к. Вы не можете удалить роль @everyone

```js
if(cmd === "clearroles") {
    message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
        if (role.editable && role.id !== message.guild.id) role.delete()
    });
}
```

Comment: Всё равно возникает ошибка точно такая же ошибка

Comment: Добавил еще одну проверку, теперь работает корректно @DChannel

Comment: Теперь всё работает, спасибо!